# Find $x, y$ and $z$ such that $x+y+z=23$, $xy+yz+xz=144$ and $xyz=252$, where $x\gt y\gt z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, nonlinear-system

All I can think of is that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the roots of the multiples of polynomial $P(x)=x^3-23x^2+144x-252$, and I found the roots by rational root test.

However this method is not elegant IMO because if the roots are not rational, I have no idea how to find them anymore.

So, could anyone introduce me a general method or at least a better method in solving system equations such as $x+y+z=a$, $xy+yz+xz=b$ and $xyz=c$, where $a, b, c\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Just factor $252$ and check which decomposition in three factors gives $x+y+z = 23$. So, you find $3,6,14$.

Comment: Nice method, but $a,b,c$ are real numbers. Your method only works when $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I would consider it to be particular elegant. The formula for cubics is however already quite complicated, so the roots usually are determined numerically. Since the equation system is non-linear, there will probably be no better way. Of course the exact solution can become messy.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you were answering the question about real numbers.

Comment: Of, course, this is not a generally working method. But in this case it works. :-) The numbers just looked toooooo nice.

Comment: @trancelocation yes that's basically what I did but what about the cases when the roots are irrational? How would you solve this system of equations? If that is the case, do we have to rely on the formula for cubics?

Comment: But the author is interested in a general way. The exercise is designed to have a nice solution , this will rarely occur in random examples. Moreover, we will not always have a solution since the number of real roots can be less than $3$.

Comment: @Ximing : Yes. Your approach is completely right. You would be forced to solve a cubic equation. Usually one would hope to spot one "nice" real solution to reduce the degree to two.

Comment: @trancelocation Got it. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this identity:

$$(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)-abc=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

Putting values you get:

$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) =3060$

Now you have to decompose 3060 and equate factors , you will have some system of equations to solve.